# Windows Azure: Start role failed for one or more roles

Tags: azure

I have added three Roles in my application contains One web role and two worker roles. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Windows Azure sDK 1.4.

I start the solution in Administrator mode, but when I try to run the application then it gives me an error. "**Start role failed for one or more roles**." Can anyone suggest me why this error is occuring and How can resolve this error.

I guess this is something related to configuration error rather than logical error as none of the role started and before starting role it give me error.

Thanks

Comment: Can you remove the roles one by one to work out which one is/are failing? Also take a look at the compute emulator UI - the "command line" output might help you understand what is failing.

Comment: It could be any number of things.  If you're using Azure storage, are you using the correct connection (instead of using local development storage)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that everything that's not  in the GAC on a clean Windows box is bin deployed with your application. For example, ASP.NET MVC 3 requires this. This is a common reason for having startup problems in the role instance.

If you have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, try deploying with Intellitrace enabled, this will give you more insight on what's going on in the VM.